# why does my rewrite rule put a question mark at the end?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

to rewrite pages like:

```
mysite.com/eng/cat
```

to redirect to:

```
mysite.com/eng?sentence=cat
```

I made the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /eng/([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^eng/ eng\?sentence=%1? [R=301,NC,L]
```

but when i request

```
mysite.com/eng/cat
```

it rewrites like this

```
mysite.com/eng?sentence=cat?
```

i dont know why it puts a question mark at the end, i also tried

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /eng/([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^eng/ eng\?sentence=%1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /eng/([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^eng/ eng\?sentence=%1\? [R=301,NC,L]
```

which dont make any difference. any help?

my htaccess file:

```
# Use PHP5.3 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php
RewriteEngine on    


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/+eng/([^/?&\s]+) [NC]
```

RewriteRule ^ eng?sentence=%1 [R=302,NC,L,NE]

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php



Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just this rule should work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/+eng/([^/?&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ eng?sentence=%1 [R=302,NC,L,NE]
```

Make sure to test in a different browser to avoid 301 caching pitfall.

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

**Suggested htaccess file:**

```
# Use PHP5.3 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

Options -Indexes -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/+eng/([^/?&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /eng?sentence=%1 [R=302,NC,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: using firefox it rewrote as /eng?sentence=cat%3f

Comment: still rewriting as eng?sentence=cat%3f

Comment: What was the original URL entered?

Comment: originally entered /eng/cat and rewrites as eng?sentence=cat%3f

Comment: ok check the edit and test in a different browser. Also if there are other rules in your .htaccess then post your complete .htaccess code in your question.

Comment: still rewriting as eng?sentence=cat%3f

Comment: Please check your suggested `.htaccess` file in my answer.

Comment: writes as eng?sentence=cat%3f in firefox (24.0), works in chrome

Comment: other urls worked while /cat did not. i cleared cash and restarted ff and now it seems to work. thank you for your time!

Comment: Oh perfect. Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.